# Error while adding phone gap platform with Xcode 6.0-beta

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When i using command

```
cordova platform add ios
```

I am getting this issues

```
Creating ios project...
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Cordova can only run in Xcode version 4.6 or greater.
Error: /Users/ykorshev/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.5.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Xcode beta 6 with Xcode command line developer tools are installed. I am using Mac OS X v10.9.3

Comment: Since this is a beta version of `xcode` you should post this as a bug to phonegap in their support forums, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use this:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/
```

this works fine for me

Comment: Note: Make sure you find your own particular directory, for example mine was: /Applications/Xcode6-Beta4.app/